# Word-Request: "Consider solutions" "Projectively alter"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm editing someone's manuscript. It uses the phrase "projectively altering the politics", I believe, to mean thinking through possible strategies or considering various changes to a political situation.

This phrase *projectively alter* is really awkward but the idea is pretty simple. I think I must be forgetting a very common word. *Strategizing?*

**I am looking for a word that means to think through possible changes to a situation and their consequences.**

*Hypothesizing* kind of works, so does *brainstorming*, but are inspecific.  *Thought-experimenting* carries the meaning well enough, though it's not an improvement and is just as awkward.

**Example usage:**

> The engineer identified flaws in the current system. She ---- the set-up – thinking through various ways she could change it and what the effects of those changes would be – and developed a strategy for a revision.

Comment: The manuscript may mean that there's a possibility that the politics will be altered in the future.  _project_ may mean _foresee_

Answer (score 1):

One such word is ***weigh*** (typically preceded by *carefully*).

ODO:

> **[weigh](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/weigh)**
> *VERB*
>
> **2** Assess the nature or importance of, especially with a view to a decision or action.
> ‘the consequences of the move would need to be
> very carefully weighed’
>
> ‘Nonetheless, he stressed that the matter would have to be carefully
> weighed by the government before any final decision could be made.’

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

> ***Devise*** [from Oxford living dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/devise)
>   *[WITH OBJECT]*
>
> 1 Plan or invent (a complex procedure, system, or mechanism) by careful thought.
>
> *‘a training programme should be devised’*
>
> *‘a complicated game of his own devising’*

although, perhaps you really want to emphasize that it is only a test?

maybe *devise a prototype*

I'm not sure but **re-devise** is a bit stretched even if it fits the rules

( re-engineer might work although that might take something to a further stage of completion)

Edit/addition:

Commonly coupled words with devise are *alternative* and *solution*
*devise an alternative*,  *devise a solution*